# "integer multiple" vs. "integral multiple"

Tags: phrases, differences, expressions, adjectives, mathematics

> 1. Nine is an integer multiple of three.
> 2. Nine is an integral multiple of three.

Which is more common?

If both are accepted, what's the subtle difference between them?

Comment: Another possible confusion.  "Integral" in math can be about this thing ∫ (hope it comes out).

Comment: @GEdgar that's the symbol for the sense I mentioned. There are yet others.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As a rule if we have a single-word noun, and if there is a single-word adjective with the same meaning that we get from using the noun as the modifier (especially a directly related one), then while using the noun as a modifier for another noun is acceptable, using the adjective is the more popular decision, and tends to read as more graceful English to many.

In this case however:

1. *Integer* is better known than *integral* in this sense.
2. *Integral* is well-known in other senses, such as "an essential part".
3. *Integral* has other senses in mathematics, such as the result of integration in calculus, so even those well-aware of the meaning related to *integer* may have a reason to avoid it.

So while there's no difference in meaning, and you certainly can use *integral*, there is a good argument in favour of *integer* here.

I favour *integral*, but then that's precisely because I'm the sort of person who spends more time on ELU than the mathematics stack-exchange. I'm not the target audience.

Comment: +1 for setting personal preference aside in favor of the target audience.

Answer (score 11):

Both are accepted. I don't believe there is a difference. As to which is more common, on the arXiv, there are over [7000](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathematics+mathematical&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=mWr&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%3aarxiv.org+%22integer+multiple%22&oq=site%3aarxiv.org+%22integer+multiple%22&gs_l=serp.3...229900.237594.0.237836.33.33.0.0.0.0.254.4257.4j27j2.33.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.K-Z95ONVczs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42661473,d.dmQ&fp=46c83184b0067790&biw=1366&bih=574) hits for "integer multiple" and only around [1500](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathematics+mathematical&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%3aarxiv.org+%22integral+multiple%22&oq=site%3aarxiv.org+%22integral+multiple%22&gs_l=serp.3...51226.51927.1.52393.3.3.0.0.0.0.146.327.2j1.3.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.4.psy-ab.YufTF9awG9s&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42661473,d.dmQ&fp=46c83184b0067790&biw=1366&bih=574) hits for "integral multiple", so even among mathematicians and physicists, "integer multiple" is more common.

Answer (score 1):

"**Integer** multiple" seems like a much better term to me, simply because it eliminates any possible confusion that can arise from the word "integral" (like the integral for antiderivatives etc).